# Datatables jquery error ajax canceled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Estoy realizando un catalogo de *kardex* del empleado en donde tengo 2 instancias del plugin *datatables* de [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

La primer petición se realiza de manera correcta pero la segunda manda un error `ajax canceled`.

No tengo muy en claro por que sale este error, al parecer la primer petición tarda y hace que cancele la segunda o bien no se si sea un tema de *datatables*.

Lo que he logrado hasta el momento es poner un `delay: 500` en la petición pero esta solución no me gusta

algun consejo?

[Post en ingles al parecer es el mismo problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175340/disable-initial-automatic-ajax-call-datatable-server-side-paging)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que deberias postear tu codigo para poderte ayudar

Comment: Deberías de revisar [este post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790065/how-to-put-multiple-jquery-datatables-in-one-page) en inglés, habla bastante sobre tu situación.

Answer (score 3):

Una forma de controlar los posibles errores al recibir los datos vía AJAX, es utilizando 2 funciones.

Ejemplo:

Función getAllUsers: Encargada de llamar los datos.

Función mostrarDatosDataTable: Encargada de llenar el datatable y poder visualizar los datos.

Versión Jquery DataTables : 1.10.7

```
//Global variables
var oTableTR;

//función que muestra los datos en el datatable
function mostrarDatosDataTable(result) {
    try {
        oTableTR = $('#listaDatosDt').DataTable({
            "aLengthMenu": [[15, 30, 60, 120, -1], [15, 30, 60, 120, "All"]],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "scrollX": true,
            "aaData": result,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "usuarioId" }, { "mDataProp": "usuarioNombre" }, { "mDataProp": "usuarioDocumento" }, { "mDataProp": "usuarioEstado" }
            ],
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]]
        });
    } catch (exception) {
        message("Error", "Attention", "error");
    }
    return false;
};

//función que llama los datos
var getAllUsers = function () {
    var datae = { 'param': 'param' };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebServices/Usuarios.asmx/GetAllUsers",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(datae),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var data = result.d;
            try {
                var dataJson = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (dataJson.status === "ok") {
                    oTableTR = $('#listaDatosDt').DataTable();
                    oTableTR.destroy();
                    try {
                        mostrarDatosDataTable(dataJson.data);
                    } catch (exception) {
                        message("Error", "Attention", "error");
                    }


                } else {
                    if (dataJson.data === "NoSession") {
                        document.location.href = "index.html?BackPageSession=NoSession";
                    } else {
                        message("Error", "Attention", "error");
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                message("Error", "Attention", "error");
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            message("Error", "Attention", "error");
        }

    });
    return false;
}

//llamado función
getAllUsers();
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez, si tu problema es la ejecución simultánea de las distintas instancias del pluging con sus respectivas llamadas ajax, yo intentaría configurar el ajax de forma no asíncrona (async:false). Desconosco si esta opción es posible en el pluging, pero es una propiedad de ajax por lo qie debiera funcionar.
Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

no puedes volver a iniciar la tabla lo que puedes hacer es limpiar la tabla y volverla a poblar de registros.

```
// instancias la tabla
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#you_table') ) {
    oTable = $('#you_table').dataTable(options);
}else{
    oTable = $('#you_table').dataTable();
}

// Limpiar registros
oTable.fnClearTable();

// Poblar la tabla - pueder usar for(){} de javascript o jquery
// yourData representa tu arreglo de kardex del empleado
$.each( yourData , function(index, valor){
   oTable.fnAddData(valor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No se puede reinicializar una tabla que ya ha sido inicializada por `DataTable`.
Para ello debes corroborar si la tabla ha sido inicializada con esta función:

```
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#example' ) ) {
  //Inicializar dataTable.
  $('#example').dataTable();
}
```

Con esta función, no te debería cancelar la segunda petición que se muestra en tu imagen, y avanzar correctamente con las demás peticiones.
Acá la documentación: [Doc](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable%28%29)

Comment: Hola gracias por responder tengo 3 instancias diferentes oTable = $('#listado').dataTable({}); oTableEmpleados = $('#listadoEmpleados').dataTable({}); oTable = $('#listadoDetalle').dataTable({}); cada una con su propia configuracion

Comment: @Gussjq ok, entonces ese no es el problema, no podrías poner el detalle del error de la cancelación de la petición?

Comment: Este es el codigo donde estan las instacionas del plugin https://github.com/gussjq/error_datatables/blob/master/kardex.js